# Getting the name of the textbox currently in focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do you get the name of the textbox currently in focus on XAML applications?

I've tried the below, but keep getting the following error message: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What am I doing wrong?

```
var textbox = Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox;
MessageBox.Show(textbox.Name);
```

Comment: I bet this is an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the focused element is not currently a TextBox, then that will return `null`. Would it be acceptable in your case to just do an `if textbox != null` before the `MessageBox.Show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element that has focus is not a `TextBox`, you're going to get the exception you're seeing, so you should test for that:

```
var textbox = Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox;

if (textbox != null)
    MessageBox.Show(textbox.Name);
```

Also, if this code is being executed in a button click (for example), you'll have to make sure the button can't steal focus from whatever element currently has it by setting "Focusable" to false:

```
<Button Content="Press" Focusable="False" Command="{Binding Path=PressCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the problem. The button press kept stealing the focus from the textbox element.